# MKMapView black screen sometimes when reload my APP

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have issue with my mapView.

[image]

I don't know where is problem.

It is my code:

```
 mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tframe.size.width, tframe.size.height- size50)];
        mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
        mapView.delegate = self;
        [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
        [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        [self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

Any idea?

Comment: Make sure you are not creating multiple instance of MKMapView.

Comment: this problem is from here:  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end]; Any idea how to fix it?